# Getting 3 consecutive aces

Tags: probability

Five cards are drawn from a well shuffled deck of 52 cards. The cards are drawn one by one without replacement. 
Find the probability of GETTING EXACTLY THREE CONSECUTIVE ACES.

I've tried a lot but i'm getting nowhere.Please help...... 
Thank you in advance ...

Comment: Well, the possible patterns are $A_1A_2A_3XY$, $XA_1A_2A_3Y$, and $XYA_1A_2A_3$ where $X,Y$ are not aces, yes?  You can persuade yourself that all three have the same probability, or just do the three separately.  Note:  I am assuming that "exactly" means you are excluding, say, $A_1A_2A_3A_4X$.  If I'm wrong about that you should clarify.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact answer

Comment: That's not how the site works. Most people here don't want to do someone's homework for them...show some effort!  Can you, say, compute the probability of the first pattern $A_1A_2A_3XY$?  Also, please answer my question about four aces.

Comment: Actually i am not able to interpret what you have written

Comment: Not sure what more I can say.  The first pattern just means:  "first card an ace, second card an ace, third card an ace, fourth card a non-ace, fifth card a non-ace".  The probability that the first card is an ace is, of course, $\frac 4{52}$ and continuing....

Comment: Got it.. Thanks

Comment: But, really, you need to clarify the four ace question.  Would $A_1A_2A_3XA_4$ be a "good" sequence for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability of $\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\green{X}\color\green{X}$ is $(\color\red  { 4}\cdot\color\red  { 3}\cdot\color\red  { 2}\cdot\color\green{48}\cdot\color\green{47})/(52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48)$
- The probability of $\color\green{X}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\green{X}$ is $(\color\green{48}\cdot\color\red  { 4}\cdot\color\red  { 3}\cdot\color\red  { 2}\cdot\color\green{47})/(52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48)$
- The probability of $\color\green{X}\color\green{X}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}$ is $(\color\green{48}\cdot\color\green{47}\cdot\color\red  { 4}\cdot\color\red  { 3}\cdot\color\red  { 2})/(52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48)$
- The probability of $\color\red  {A}\color\green{X}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}$ is $(\color\red  { 4}\cdot\color\green{48}\cdot\color\red  { 3}\cdot\color\red  { 2}\cdot\color\red  { 1})/(52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48)$
- The probability of $\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\red  {A}\color\green{X}\color\red  {A}$ is $(\color\red  { 4}\cdot\color\red  { 3}\cdot\color\red  { 2}\cdot\color\green{48}\cdot\color\red  { 1})/(52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48)$

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be attempted using combinatorics and classical approach to probability, i.e, the N(E)/N(S) approach.
Let us take two cases : One with three aces consecutively(AAAXX) and the other with four aces, with three of them consecutive and the fourth one,a non ace card(AAAXA).Here A denotes the Ace card and the X denotes the non ace card.

CASE I:
AAAXX: We can choose the three aces from four in 4C3 ways and the two non aces in 48C2 ways.Considering the three aces as a group as we usually do, these can be arranged among themselves in 3! ways and the non aces can be arranged among themselves in 2! ways.

This arrangement of three consecutive aces can be satisfied in three ways , namely AAAXX,XAAAX,XXAAA.

So total no of ways of arranging in this fashion is 
                          4C3.48C2.3!.2!.3

and the total no of cases is 52C5.5! as selection as well as arrangement is to be considered.

CASE II:
AAAXA:We can similarly choose the three aces from four in 4C3 ways and the non ace in 48C1 ways.The last ace can be chosen in only one way as there is only one left. Considering the three aces as a group as we usually do, these can be arranged among themselves in 3! ways.

There are two ways of satisfying this arrangement namely AAAXA and AXAAA.
So total no of ways of arranging in this fashion is 
                          4C3.48C1.1.3!.2

and the total no of cases is 52C5.5! , same as before.

Our condition is satisfied if either of these arrangements is followed and hence, using addition theorem, total no of ways is 
            N(E)=(4C3.48C2.3!.2!.3)+(4C3.48C1.1.3!.2).

Our probability is N(E)/N(S)={(4C3.48C2.3!.2!.3)+(4C3.48C1.1.3!.2)}/52C5.5!
that is 858/1624350 and finally 143/ 270725.

I hope this satisfies your query...............................